Android application failing with SQLiteDatabaseLockedException
We are getting the following fatal error in our Android app:
Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException database is locked (code 5 SQLITE_BUSY)

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecute (SQLiteConnection.java)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.execute (SQLiteConnection.java:648)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.beginTransactionUnchecked (SQLiteSession.java:325)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.beginTransaction (SQLiteSession.java:300)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction (SQLiteDatabase.java:568)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction (SQLiteDatabase.java:478)
androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction (FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.kt:55)
androidx.room.RoomDatabase.internalBeginTransaction (RoomDatabase.kt:529)
androidx.room.RoomDatabase.beginTransaction (RoomDatabase.kt:511)
androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.trySetRunning (WorkerWrapper.java:487)
androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.runWorker (WorkerWrapper.java:266)
androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.run (WorkerWrapper.java:144)
androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutorImpl$Task.run (SerialExecutorImpl.java:96)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:919) 


We have tried a number of methods to catch the error as suggested by others:
suspend fun <T> safeDaoRequest(
    maxRetries: Int = 3,
    delayMillis: Long = 1000,
    action: suspend () -> T
): T? {
    var attempt = 0
    while (attempt < maxRetries) {
        try {
            return action()
        } catch (t: Throwable) {


            attempt++
            if (attempt >= maxRetries) {
                return null
            }
            delay(delayMillis)
        }
    }
    return null
}


The call to the dao is passed to the function as follows:
    override suspend fun read(): Flow<List<T>>? {
        return safeDaoRequest {
            dao.read()
        }
    }


Thing is that the stacktrace doesn't show any of our code.
Also, when we add logging to the catch section we don't get anything.
